# Google Tag Manager - Regex match

Tags: regex, google-tag-manager

I want to check if a specific string is included in a GTM variable. The value of this variable is a first-party-cookie value decoded via URI looking like this:

```
"\"prodirversion\":5,\"panellanguage\":\"de\",\"preferences\":false,"\"marketing\":true,\"necessary\":true,\"statistics\":false,\"social_"
```

I now want to check if the following string is included.

**marketing":true**

I created another variable with a regex table and tried different regex expressions but nothing seems to work. It works on online regex tester but not in Google Tag Manager.

My guess would be the following but it doesn't work.

```
marketing\\":true
```

or

```
marketing.{3}true
```

or

```
marketing\\.{2}true
```

[GTM variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7q0M.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Some Regex engines will have an error on not escaping `"` char in `marketing\\":true`

Try escaping it like this: `marketing\\\":true`, and it should match.

Update:

- `marketing":true` seems to be working in `GTM`
- from that, we can conclude that escaping character `\` in input string is for show only in GTM case, and should be ignored when regex testing/debugging.

Comment: Unfortunately did not work

Comment: @Manuel-BWK, 
I've tested the exact input in the question on [all flavors of regex](https://regex101.com/r/bDj1GM/1) - try switching flavors and see.

my next assumption is that the input may be different for the engine/flavor google using in this case, than the one in the question.

I would try:
1. matching with one escape `\` for `"` only - e.g. `marketing\":true`
2. matching with no escape - e.g. `marketing":true`

Comment: GTM uses JS regex engine. I'm pretty sure the author is misusing it in a different way. It would be helpful if they could share their full regex and test on regex101.

Comment: It is not necessary to escape quotes. Quotes are escaped only because they are using as string literal delimiters.

Comment: @RyszardCzech I agree, that is probably the missing link here, thus, my suggestion to  try  it on GTM without escaping `"` or even `\\`

Comment: @LironZ
Your second suggestion: `marketing":true` seems to work. on regex101 it doesn't work but in GTM it seems to work :)